# Did Apple make magnetic Smart Cover accessories for the iPad Air 1?

Tags: ipad, accessories, smart-cover

My first iPad (which I don't have anymore) had an Apple brand Smart Cover which held onto the iPad with magnets.

It was very convenient as you could easily remove and reattach the Smart Cover in a few seconds.

My current iPad is an iPad Air 1 (model number A1474) and I am looking for a similar magnetic Smart Cover, one whose hinges attach magnetically to the side of the iPad without needing the iPad to be in a case.

Was there ever such an accessory?

Comment: Perhaps you should be on ebay.

Comment: @SolarMike be? You mean look? I did but all I find are ones with the case, not the magnetic ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they did. In fact, you can still buy them here:

https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ4L2ZM/A/ipad-smart-cover-charcoal-gray

Comment: I can *almost* buy them there ("currently available")